# Get variable name from variable value in SASS/SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to access variable within an `@each` loop using defined value like in the following example:

```
$car:true;
$people:false;
$job:false;

    @mixin options($someval){
        @each $prefix in car,people,job{ 
            @if $#{$prefix} == true{
                    //some CSS...
            }       
        }
    }
```

Variable would be a sort of "semaphores" that define whether print or not Css rules.

My big doubt is how can I check over dynamically defined variables name ?

I've tried with `$#{$prefix}` but it doesn't work.

EDIT ---------------------------
I'd like to obtain this CSS

```
car-something: 34px;
```

Where the word "car" is taken from `$prefix` and in the first round of `@each` loop `$#{$prefix}` becomes `$car`

The problem is on `$#{$prefix}` ... it doesn't work :P  i get an error

Comment: Can you expand on how you would use this in practice?

Comment: @maxbeatty thank you, I've edited my question adding more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but since it has no valid answer, here it is

You need to pass a map to `@each`

```
$car:true;
$people:false;
$job:false;

@mixin options($someval){
    @each $key, $val in (car: $car, people: $people, job: $job) { 
        @if $val == true{
            #{$key}-something: $someval
        }       
    }
}

test {
    @include options(34px)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to interpolate a variable name, pass a list to the mixin.

```
$car: true;
$people: false;
$job: false;

$thing-list: $car, $people, $job;

@mixin thingamajig($thing-list) {
  @each $thing in $thing-list {
    @if $thing {
      // Some CSS
    }
  }
}
```